# Query to write hops and return all the properties from the middle nodes or a better way to do it and skip hops?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Node A is connected to Node E through different nodes B (B can be repeating), C and D etc as given below.

```
(A)--(C)--(D)--(E)
(A)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(E)
(A)--(B)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(E)
(A)--(B)--(B)--(B)--(C)--(D)--(E)
```

There could be up to 7 B nodes between A and C or no B node at all (like the first case above).

Question: How to get all the E1, E2, E3, E4 connected to A1 with a single query and return properties from all A, B, C, D and E nodes? I could not return the properties using the hops.

```
MATCH (A {Id:30})-[*1..6]-(E) RETURN DISTINCT A.Name, E.Name;
```

But we want to return B.Name (If there are multiple B nodes in the middle their names too), C.Name and D.Name too. Happy to skip hopping completely if required. Help please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// in case there is always A,C and E, you can look for
// paths with length 3 to 6
MATCH path=(A)-[*3..6]-(E)

// return the name of each node in the same order
RETURN [n IN nodes(path) | n.name] AS nodeNames
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A` through `E` are node [labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/3.5/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels), this query should get all paths that match your pattern (with 0 to 7 `B` nodes between the `A` and `C` nodes), and return distinct lists of node `Name` values:

```
MATCH p=(:A)-[*..8]-(:C)--(:D)--(:E)
WHERE ALL(n IN NODES(p)[1..-3] WHERE 'B' IN LABELS(n))
RETURN DISTINCT [m IN NODES(p) | m.Name] AS names
```

In general, the query would be more efficient if you could also specify the relationship types and their directionality.